# How to compare two FlowDocuments?

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox, flowdocument

I want to compare a `FlowDocument` to a document of `Rich Text Box`. Here is the code

```
if (rtbEditor.Document != (XamlReader.Parse(currentNote.content) as FlowDocument))
{
   MessageBox.Show("Overwrite existing Note?", "Save", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
}
```

At the beginning I set `rtbEditor`'s document as

```
rtbEditor.Document = XamlReader.Parse(currentNote.content) as FlowDocument;
```

Thus, unless the content of `rtbEditor` is changed, I thought that the if statement should not execute,but it does. Probably this is not the way to compare `FlowDocuments`. If this is not the correct way then how can we compare two documents?

If it is necessary, the `currentNote.content` is a string containing xml content of `FlowDocument`.

Comment: It is comparing two objects and those are different objects.  I bet if you created two XamlReader.Parse(currentNote.content) as FlowDocument they not even be the same.

Comment: @Frisbee I know. I just posted the code, because that is the only way I could think of.

Comment: Could could either of the two `FlowDocument` instances have embedded bitmaps?

Comment: @dbc No. They are just text related xml elements. Actually content is very simple. Only forecolor, boldness and stuff like that are set.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have no images in your `FlowDocument` instances, you can just serialize to XAML and compare the XAML.  First, create extension methods to generate the XAML strings:

```
public static class FrameworkContentElementExtensions
{
    public static string ToXaml(this FrameworkContentElement element) // For instance, a FlowDocument
    {
        if (element == null)
            return null;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb))
        {
            XamlWriter.Save(element, xmlWriter);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static string ToFormattedXamlString(this FrameworkContentElement element)
    {
        if (element == null)
            return null;
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true, IndentChars = "    " };
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings))
        {
            XamlWriter.Save(element, xmlWriter);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
if (rtbEditor.Document.ToXaml() != currentNote.content)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Overwrite existing Note?", "Save", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
}
```

Note that if the XAML differs only because of cosmetic formatting (XML indentation), since XAML documents are valid XML, you can [parse your XAML to an `XElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468714%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use [`XNode.DeepEquals()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.deepequals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You can also serialize a `FrameworkContentElement` directly to an `XElement` without the intervening string representation for improved performance:

```
public static class FrameworkContentElementExtensions
{
    public static XElement ToXamlXElement(this FrameworkContentElement element) // For instance, a FlowDocument
    {
        if (element == null)
            return null;
        var doc = new XDocument();
        using (var xmlWriter = doc.CreateWriter())
        {
            XamlWriter.Save(element, xmlWriter);
        }
        var xElement = doc.Root;
        if (xElement != null)
            xElement.Remove();
        return xElement;
    }
}
```

And then

```
var docXaml = rtbEditor.Document.ToXamlXElement();
var currentNoteXaml = XElement.Parse(currentNote.content);
if (!XNode.DeepEquals(docXaml, currentNoteXaml))
{
   MessageBox.Show("Overwrite existing Note?", "Save", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
}
```

If you are concerned there might be embedded messages and want to generate a warning message in this case, see [Finding all Images in a FlowDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899852/finding-all-images-in-a-flowdocument).